# pattern recognition and subsetting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 3 columns. I would like to subset to subset the dataframe if the column value reaches 1 again and mark that as 1 observation and go on till the end of the file.

dataframe:

```
colA   colB  colC    
a12     3      1    
c45     4      0    
d36     4      0    
e97     5      0
h65     3      1
k67     3      1
l54     5      0
```

so I should be able to subset 3 observations as `[a12,c45,d36.e97],[h65],[k67,l54]` and pass this to another dataframe which has only the column names and mark the values present here as 1 and rest 0 to pass it to ML algorithm.

I tried pulling the pattern but getting an error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `cumsum` with colC, then using that result as group key

```
df.colC.cumsum()
Out[282]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    3
Name: colC, dtype: int64
df.groupby(df.colC.cumsum()).colA.apply(list)
Out[284]: 
colC
1    [a12, c45, d36, e97]
2                   [h65]
3              [k67, l54]
Name: colA, dtype: object
```

Comment: this did not work it is giving just the type list if i try to print the list

Comment: in the last cumulative column i would like them to be added but not as zeroes in between . the output i got was not giving the cumulative for all the rows . it was skipping for the zeros and adding only ones.and also i was not able to get the col C as above. i want the output as above.

Comment: this is what i wrote:for file in filenameList:
 df = pd.read_table(file,header=None,names=['A'],skiprows=1)
 df = pd.DataFrame(df.A.str.rsplit('_',1).tolist(),columns = ['A','B'])
 df['A'] = df.A.astype(str).str.cat(df.B.astype(str), sep='_')
 df = df[df.B >= str(thres)]
 df['C'] = df.B == str(thres)
 lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
 lab_enc.fit(df['C'])
 variable = lab_enc.transform(df['C'])
 df['D'] = variable.astype(int)
 cumsums = df.groupby(['D']).cumsum()
 cumsums = cumsums.apply(list)
 df['cumulatives'] = cumsums.astype(int)
 print df